# Passing the scala list element as a parameter in a filter expression

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, isin

I have a list of dates in scala like below.

```
ListBuffer(2021-10-01, 2021-10-02, 2021-10-03, 2021-10-04)
```

I want to pass each element in the list to the below variable and get the count.

```
val fctExistingDF = spark.read.table(existingTable).filter("event_date","date from the list")
fctExistingDF.count()
```

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isin`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val values = Seq("2021-10-01", "2021-10-02", "2021-10-03", "2021-10-04")
spark.read.table(existingTable).filter(col("event_date").isin(values:_*)).count()
```